# I have a repeated method and I don't know how can I use abstract with ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

this is my code

```
@DatabaseField
String image;      
Bitmap bitmapImage;

public void convertStringImageToBitmapImage() {
    if (image != null) {        
        bitmapImage = ImageHelper.CreateBitmapFromString(image);            
        image = "";
    }
}
```

I use this method to convert from string base64 to bitmap and I use it in every entity class that use ormlite. Every time I want to change the ormlite fields I need to comment bitmaps code because DatabaseConfigUtil makes errors for me after that I uncomment them. I may put this code in abstract class but I cannot but image DataField in the abstract class because ormlite will not work good with this structure.

What is the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create Base class and write your method by using static keyword.
Use this method anywhere of your project.

By using Classname, ex:Base.covertStringImageToBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmapImage,String image);

```
public class Base extends Activity {
    public void convertStringImageToBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmapImage, String image) {
        if (image != null) {
            bitmapImage = ImageHelper.CreateBitmapFromString(image);
            image = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an abstract class. Put your code in a utils class and call this method statically from your entities using `Utils.convertStringImageToBitmapImage(image)`:

```
    public class Utils {
        public static Bitmap convertStringImageToBitmapImage(String image) {
            if (image != null) {
                return ImageHelper.CreateBitmapFromString(image);
                // this is useless now
                // image = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

If you can edit code inside ImageHelper, you can handle null argument scenario inside `CreateBitmapFromString` method and call directly `ImageHelper.CreateBitmapFromString(image)` from your entities.